# Cannot deploy with Capistrano 3.5.0 after upgrade to Ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3, ruby-2.3

Worked with Ruby 2.1. This happens only when deploying to multiple servers at once. Server is Ubuntu 14.04. Rails 4.2.6. Same behaviour with Cap 3.2 and master.

It is creating log symlink inside log folder instead of inside main app folder.  Same is for log/log, public/system/system, tmp/sockets/sockets, tmp/pids/pids, tmp/cache/cache, vendor/bundle/bundle

Has anyone experienced this?  Any advice would be appreciated.

my gemfile

```
gem 'capistrano', '3.5.0'
gem 'capistrano-sidekiq'
gem 'capistrano-rvm'
gem 'capistrano-bundler'
gem 'capistrano-scm-copy'
```

Detailed errors

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as ubuntu@stg1.server.com: ln exit status: 1
ln stdout: Nothing written
ln stderr: ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/opt/.../releases/20160720180448/log/log’: File exists
SSHKit::Command::Failed: ln exit status: 1
ln stdout: Nothing written
ln stderr: ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/opt/.../releases/20160720180448/log/log’: File exists
Tasks: TOP => deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as ubuntu@stg1.server.com: ln exit status: 1
ln stdout: Nothing written
ln stderr: ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/opt/.../releases/20160720180448/log/log’: File exists

** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:
```

capistrano.log

```
INFO [87787bde] Finished in 5.780 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [70bb86bb] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.1 do bundle exec rake assets:clean as dmitry@localhost
INFO [70bb86bb] Finished in 17.418 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [1812e625] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.3.1 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile as dmitry@localhost
INFO [1812e625] Finished in 56.384 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [bcc87542] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/shared /opt/amplo/stg/releases as ubuntu@stg1.server.com
INFO [3c49af83] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/shared /opt/amplo/stg/releases as ubuntu@stg2.server.com
INFO [ab6ee55a] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/shared /opt/amplo/stg/releases as ubuntu@stg3.server.com
INFO [3c49af83] Finished in 0.433 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [ab6ee55a] Finished in 0.477 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [bcc87542] Finished in 0.479 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [d0a5aafb] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/shared/log /opt/amplo/stg/shared/tmp/pids /opt/amplo/stg/shared/tmp/cache /opt/amplo/stg/shared/tmp/sockets /opt/amplo/stg/shared/vendor/bundle /opt/amplo/stg/shared/public/system as ubuntu@stg2.server.com
INFO [036d4589] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/shared/log /opt/amplo/stg/shared/tmp/pids /opt/amplo/stg/shared/tmp/cache /opt/amplo/stg/shared/tmp/sockets /opt/amplo/stg/shared/vendor/bundle /opt/amplo/stg/shared/public/system as ubuntu@stg1.server.com
INFO [69145663] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/shared/log /opt/amplo/stg/shared/tmp/pids /opt/amplo/stg/shared/tmp/cache /opt/amplo/stg/shared/tmp/sockets /opt/amplo/stg/shared/vendor/bundle /opt/amplo/stg/shared/public/system as ubuntu@stg3.server.com
INFO [d0a5aafb] Finished in 0.038 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [69145663] Finished in 0.039 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [036d4589] Finished in 0.042 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [791ddedf] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724 as ubuntu@stg2.server.com
INFO [01ac821d] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724 as ubuntu@stg3.server.com
INFO [3a5af02f] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724 as ubuntu@stg1.server.com
INFO [3a5af02f] Finished in 0.028 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [01ac821d] Finished in 0.031 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [791ddedf] Finished in 0.031 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 10.02%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 10.02%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 10.02%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 20.05%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 30.01%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 20.05%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 20.05%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 40.03%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 30.01%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 30.01%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 50.05%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 40.03%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 60.02%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 50.05%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 40.03%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 70.04%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 60.02%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 50.05%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 80.01%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 70.04%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 90.03%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 80.01%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 60.02%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 100.0%
INFO [5b4b855e] Running /usr/bin/env tar -xzf /tmp/tmp.kv2Vm4c575 -C /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724 as ubuntu@stg3.server.com
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 90.03%
INFO [5b4b855e] Finished in 0.614 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [ef4235a4] Running /usr/bin/env rm /tmp/tmp.kv2Vm4c575 as ubuntu@stg3.server.com
INFO [ef4235a4] Finished in 0.080 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 70.04%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 100.0%
INFO [13660674] Running /usr/bin/env tar -xzf /tmp/tmp.xNKgZ200Pm -C /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724 as ubuntu@stg1.server.com
INFO [13660674] Finished in 0.596 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [51117c6c] Running /usr/bin/env rm /tmp/tmp.xNKgZ200Pm as ubuntu@stg1.server.com
INFO [51117c6c] Finished in 0.047 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 80.01%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 90.03%
INFO Uploading archive.tar.gz 100.0%
INFO [e6e1a785] Running /usr/bin/env tar -xzf /tmp/tmp.uJQfuNoStV -C /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724 as ubuntu@stg2.server.com
INFO [e6e1a785] Finished in 0.559 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [96bb1493] Running /usr/bin/env rm /tmp/tmp.uJQfuNoStV as ubuntu@stg2.server.com
INFO [96bb1493] Finished in 0.038 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [d95f701a] Running /usr/bin/env echo "" >> REVISION as ubuntu@stg2.server.com
INFO [92fc67ba] Running /usr/bin/env echo "" >> REVISION as ubuntu@stg3.server.com
INFO [a5752527] Running /usr/bin/env echo "" >> REVISION as ubuntu@stg1.server.com
INFO [d95f701a] Finished in 0.026 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [92fc67ba] Finished in 0.031 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [a5752527] Finished in 0.028 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [214b97cd] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724 /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/tmp /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/vendor /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/public as ubuntu@stg1.server.com
INFO [4dd15166] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724 /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/tmp /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/vendor /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/public as ubuntu@stg2.server.com
INFO [c4aa42d6] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724 /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/tmp /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/vendor /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/public as ubuntu@stg3.server.com
INFO [4dd15166] Finished in 0.032 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [214b97cd] Finished in 0.031 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [c4aa42d6] Finished in 0.034 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [a0e1582d] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /opt/amplo/stg/shared/log /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/log as ubuntu@stg2.server.com
INFO [ff0ea545] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /opt/amplo/stg/shared/log /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/log as ubuntu@stg1.server.com
INFO [fae235dc] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /opt/amplo/stg/shared/log /opt/amplo/stg/releases/20160720191724/log as ubuntu@stg3.server.com
INFO [a0e1582d] Finished in 0.028 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [fae235dc] Finished in 0.030 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

Comment: Could you post your deploy.rb?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is really weird but after I deleted by /opt/app_name/* folder and redeployed this started working.  Sorry to have posted silly question.